# Best way to sync NSTableView automatic reloading and removing objects

Tags: objective-c, nstableview

Let's assume we have a Mac app with a NSTableView inside it (with a DownloadTableView sublassed from NSTableView and DownloadCell sublassed from NSActionCell to display progress bar and all info related to the item). Inside my app controller I have a NSMutableArray to hold the objects that will be displayed in the tableView (Download).
Currently I have also a timer in the controller which causes `[[self tableView] reloadData]` every second to show the progress on each object (download).

I don't think that's the best way to refresh the tableView as when I try to remove one element from the mutableArray I often get race conditions (and therefore exceptions). For example the view was currently refreshing and I removed one element from the array. The app might complain inside `- (NSCell *)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView dataCellForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row`, [downloadCell setRepresentedObject:download] the download may no longer be in the array, therefore exception arises that it is out of bounds of the array. Or if I drag & drop elements which sometime requires removing and re-adding object to the array.

Anyone has a better idea on that subject?

Comment: You could be more focused on which rows/columns are reloaded by calling `reloadDataForRowIndexes:columnIndexes:` only when something actually changes.

Comment: Each Download has a State property, from which I can tell if it is downloading or not. Also dug into Transmission code, which is open-source and seems they're only using reloadData only when adding new objects, re-arranging the items etc. But the UI still updates every second with each download progress, but haven't found out how yet.

Comment: Have you thought about using Cocoa Bindings? The NSArrayController that you would use to store your objects would manage the adding and removing of cells from your table for you, preventing race conditions. It could also handle displaying the progress of downloads.